# export Blockchain ETH wallet to Myether wallet

Tags: wallets, export

Thank you User for your answer. I need to now ask/present this additional information regarding my original question.

**strong text**I initiated a token purchase on CRPT. They are a ERC20 token. I tried to withdraw to a Blockchain ETH Wallet which does not support ERC20. Blockchain says I need to export key to a wallet that supports this. The instructions are very vague. I am trying to export key to a Myetherwallet that supports ERC20 (CRPT) Tokens.

I should note that the ERC20 tokens that were sent to blockchain are not visible in the account. It clearly states this in blockchains.

See Below Blockchain support info:

Your Blockchain wallet currently does not support ERC20 tokens. If you accidentally sent ERC20 tokens to your wallet, you will need to export your private key in order to access them. To export your ether private key, navigate to your Ether tab in the left hand side navigation. Click on Export Private Keys on the right side of the grey bar above your transaction history. Carefully read the warning message shown and click Continue. Enter your wallet password, then click Submit to view your private key. As stated in the warning, you should never share your private key with anyone. Anyone with access to your private key has the ability to spend the funds associated with it. Please note: your private key does not need to be exported to backup your ether funds. As long as you have your backup phrase written down and stored somewhere safe, they are already backed up.

Also:

At this time the Blockchain ethereum wallet does not support the sending of ethereum based tokens, known as ERC20 tokens. ***If you receive any of these tokens to your Blockchain wallet you will not be able to send them or see the balance of the tokens while logged into your wallet.*** Since you have complete control over your funds you are able to export the private key for your ethereum address and import it into any other ethereum wallet that supports ERC20 tokens.

This said, Will all contents be forwarded to MEW wallet automatically? Or will I need to somehow specify which contents I would like to export? If I need to specify, how do I do that If I cannot see any of the contents?

Help PLEASE!!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003653543-Exporting-the-private-key-for-your-Ethereum-address), you need to load up your Blockchain Ether wallet and click the "Private Keys" button in the top right corner. Once you have your private key you'll go to [MyEtherWallet.com](https://myetherwallet.com), click "Send Ether & Tokens" and select "Private Key". Then you'll paste the key from your Blockchain wallet and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. I should note that the ERC20 tokens that were sent to blockchain are not visible in the account. It clearly states this in blockchains. 
See Below Blockchain support info:

Your Blockchain wallet currently does not support ERC20 tokens. If you accidentally sent ERC20 tokens to your wallet, you will need to export your private key in order to access them. 
To export your ether private key, navigate to your Ether tab in the left hand side navigation. 
Click on Export Private Keys on the right side of the grey bar above your transaction history. 
Carefully read the warning message shown and click Continue.
Enter your wallet password, then click Submit to view your private key. 
As stated in the warning, you should never share your private key with anyone. Anyone with access to your private key has the ability to spend the funds associated with it.
Please note: your private key does not need to be exported to backup your ether funds. As long as you have your backup phrase written down and stored somewhere safe, they are already backed up.

Also:

At this time the Blockchain ethereum wallet does not support the sending of ethereum based tokens, known as ERC20 tokens. ***If you receive any of these tokens to your Blockchain wallet you will not be able to send them or see the balance of the tokens while logged into your wallet***. Since you have complete control over your funds you are able to export the private key for your ethereum address and import it into any other ethereum wallet that supports ERC20 tokens.

This said, Will all contents be forwarded to MEW wallet automatically? Or will I need to somehow specify which contents I would like to export?